# WSS - Multiple password prompts

Tags: iis, iis-6, authentication, wss-3.0, wss

I'm using WSS 3.0 SP1 with IIS 6.0 on integrated authentication. However when access Sharepoint this is what happens. You are prompted for a password when you first access the site (via IE8), and then everytime you attempt to open a document you are forced to reauthenticate. This is causing a lot of people to want to kill WSS altogether because they are sick of entering passwords. Any thoughts on how we can get rid of the prompt everytime a document is accessed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does seem to be a standard thing, have never seen a good solution to it.

Yes the integrated Windows auth (AKA NTLM and/or Kerberos) should work, but it doesn't seem to help when opening documents.

Comment: We had this set up at another company, and I don't recall being prompted on every document. I am reasonably certain that this should be possible. For now we have worked around the issue by making it a trusted site and then instructing people to allow it save their passwords. But I really hate that solution for quite a few reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all for the suggestions on how to fix this. I share my solution to solve the login prompt once and for all.

http://www.uv.mx/personal/gvera/2010/09/28/sharepoint-login-prompt-when-accessing-files-in-a-document-library/

Hope it helps you.